# .NET MAUI IsVisible MultiTrigger of StackLayout not working

Tags: xaml, maui

I am trying to set my StackLayout Visibility to False if my Picker's SelectedIndex is on the last three options and not the first two.

This is the picker's list:

```
"1 - Yes",
"2 - No",
"97 - Don't Know",
"98 - No Answer",
"99 - Not Applicable"
```

XAML:

```
<!-- Intention to Use Family Planning --> 
<StackLayout Padding="10,0,10,10"> 
    <Label Text="Intention to use Family Planning?" 
           VerticalTextAlignment="Center" 
           FontAttributes="Bold"/> 
    <Border Padding="10,0,0,0"> 
        <StackLayout> 
            <Picker x:Name="PckIntentionFP" 
                    Title="Select a Family Planning Intention Option" 
                    ItemsSource="{Binding IntentionToFamilyPlanningItems}">
            </Picker>
        </StackLayout> 
    </Border> 
</StackLayout> 

<!-- Intention Yes/No -->
<StackLayout Padding="10,0,10,10">
    <StackLayout.Triggers>
        <MultiTrigger TargetType="StackLayout">
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <BindingCondition Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference PckIntentionFP}, 
                                                    Path=SelectedIndex}" 
                                  Value="2"/>
                <BindingCondition Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference PckIntentionFP}, 
                                                    Path=SelectedIndex}" 
                                  Value="3"/>
                <BindingCondition Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference PckIntentionFP}, 
                                                    Path=SelectedIndex}"
                                  Value="4"/>
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="False" />
        </MultiTrigger>
    </StackLayout.Triggers>
    <Label Text="If 'Yes', what method? If 'No', why not?"
           FontAttributes="Bold"
           VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
    <Frame Padding="10,0,10,0"
           Margin="5">
        <Entry VerticalOptions="Center"
               TextTransform="Uppercase"
               Text="{Binding LastName}">
        </Entry>
    </Frame>
</StackLayout>
```

This is my first time asking a question here, sorry in advance.

As i run the application in my tablet it does not set the StackLayout Visibility to False when I selected the last three options.

I am really confused on what I mmight have missed on using the MultiTrigger.

Comment: I just found out that MultiTrigger only trigger if all the conditions are met. So my approach is not the way to do it. Any idea on how to do this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could use SelectedIndexChanged handler of Picker.

In xaml file:

```
<Picker x:Name="PckIntentionFP" 
    Title="Select a Family Planning Intention Option" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding IntentionToFamilyPlanningItems}"
    SelectedIndexChanged="PckIntentionFP_SelectedIndexChanged"> // add this event handler for picker

//set a name for StackLayout
<StackLayout Padding="10,0,10,10" x:Name="mystack" >
            ...
               
</StackLayout>
```

And in .cs file, implement it:

```
void PckIntentionFP_SelectedIndexChanged(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    var p = sender as Picker;
    if (p.SelectedIndex == 1 || p.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {
        mystack.IsVisible = true;
    }else
    {
        mystack.IsVisible = false;
    }
}
```

**Another way** i think you could use three parallel Data triggers for selected index of 2,3 and 4 separately.

Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You want boolean. (IsVisible). You have integer. (Selected index).

You can use Value Converters, for binding.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/converters?view=net-maui-7.0

The very first example is int to bool converter.
If you have questions, please ask.